# Elliptic Maximal Tori and Elliptic Elements

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-groups, reductive-groups

I would be grateful if someone could provide a reference/proof of the following fact (or give a counterexample if I've misunderstood and it's false!)

Let $G$ be a reductive group over a field $F$ (in practice I really only care about local and global fields). Suppose that $G$ contains an elliptic maximal $F$-torus  (i.e. a maximal torus defined over $F$ that is anisotropic modulo $Z(G)$ ). Suppose that $\gamma \in G(F)$ is an elliptic element (i.e. the identity component of the center of the identity component of the centralizer of $\gamma$ in $G$ is an elliptic torus).

Then, fact:  $\gamma$ is contained in an elliptic maximal torus.

This is alluded to on page 392 of Kottwitz's Stable Trace Formula: Elliptic Singular Terms, but I would appreciate a reference that proves this fact, or at least confirmation that I am not misunderstanding this passage.

Thanks!

Comment: By Theorem 6.21 of Platonov-Rapinchuk (algebraic groups and number theory), any reductive group over a non archimedean local field admits a maximal elliptic torus. Now let  $G_\gamma$ be the centralizer of  $\gamma$ and $T$ a maximal elliptic torus in $G_\gamma$. Then $T$ should be a maximal elliptic torus in $G$. I do not know any reference for the global case.

Comment: Replace everywhere "maximal elliptic" by "elliptic maximal" in my previous comment.

Comment: Thanks for this. I guess the Archimedean case is particularly interesting, as there one is not guaranteed an elliptic maximal torus so one would need to modify the argument.

Comment: In characteristic $0$, as in Kottwitz's paper, every element $\gamma$ lies in $C_G(\gamma)^\circ$.  Indeed, we have that $C_G(\gamma)^\circ = C_{C_G(\gamma_{\text s})^\circ}(\gamma_{\text u})^\circ$.  Since $\gamma_{\text s}$ is semisimple, it lies in a maximal torus $T$, which is contained in $C_G(\gamma_{\text s})^\circ$; and the image of $\gamma_{\text u}$ in the component group of $C_G(\gamma_{\text s})$ is unipotent and has finite order, hence is trivial (that's where we use characteristic $0$).  Thus we may replace $G$ by $C_G(\gamma_{\text s})$ …

Comment: […](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/333843/elliptic-maximal-tori-and-elliptic-elements#comment833564_333843) and so assume that $\gamma$ is unipotent.  Then again the image of $\gamma$ in the component group of $C_G(\gamma)$ is unipotent and has finite order, hence is trivial.  I don't know whether the same is true for positive characteristic.  […](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/333843/elliptic-maximal-tori-and-elliptic-elements#comment833566_333843)

Comment: […](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/333843/elliptic-maximal-tori-and-elliptic-elements#comment833565_333843) Anyway it seems that $\gamma$ is meant to be semisimple in Kottwitz's paper, so then (in all characteristics, by the torus argument above) $\gamma$ lies in $C_G(\gamma)^\circ$.

Comment: [@PaulBroussous](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/333843/elliptic-maximal-tori-and-elliptic-elements#comment833513_333843)'s comment seems to use implicitly that we're dealing with a semisimple $\gamma$ in order to conclude that it lies in the chosen torus $T$.  Note that, by assumption, there is a unique such torus in $G_\gamma$ and it's maximal elliptic in $G$, so that no sophisticated structure results are needed.

Comment: @LSpice Sorry, I meant to say that $\gamma$ is semi-simple. I'm only interested in that case.

Comment: @LSpice As I understand it, the argument of PaulBroussous relies on EVERY reductive group over F containing an elliptic maximal torus and this is not true for all F (for instance F=R). In this case, we are assuming G has an elliptic maximal torus, but I don't see how we can use that to conclude $G^0_{\gamma}$ contains such a torus.

Comment: [That](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/333843/elliptic-maximal-tori-and-elliptic-elements#comment833591_333843)'s your hypothesis (that $G_\gamma$ contains such a torus), isn't it?

Comment: No, just that $G$ does.

Comment: @LSpice Indeed I implicitely assumed $\gamma$ semisimple.

Comment: Oh, I see.  I missed that you said "$Z(C_G(\gamma)^\circ)^\circ$ elliptic" rather than "$C_G(\gamma)^\circ$ elliptic".